# Implement object manipulation polymorphically at trait level

Tags: rust, traits

Is there any way to implement the function `feed` at trait level:

```
trait Animal: Clone {

   fn is_fed(&self) -> bool;

   fn feed(&self) -> Self {
      // return clone of self where
      // is_fed returns true 
   }
}
```

In principal all the information is available at trait level.

Comment: The only way this is possible is if you return a different struct implementing Animal than you were passed in. Animal doesn't know how its implementors determine is fed.

Comment: `struct BottomlessPit; impl Animal for BottomlessPit { fn is_fed(&self) -> bool { false } }` What should `BottomlessPit.feed()` return?

Comment: @trentcl: return a subtype of BottomlessPit where the member function is_fed is overridden.

Comment: Rust doesn't have subtyping.

Comment: (Okay, okay, technically Rust does have lifetime-based subtyping for type constructors, but it doesn't have the "create a new type that is a subtype of an existing one" kind.)

Comment: @trentcl: your example is the decisive answer, make it official and I will  accept  it.